# Entity Framework 6.1.3 : InvalidOperationException after a few days of running

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, windows-services

I have a strange problem. I have a Windows service. Service runs ok on over 100 computers. But on a few of them after a few (or even a month) days it starts to throw exceptions like this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The 'X' property on 'Y' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'.
>
> in System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
>
>  in System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling[TProperty](Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName)
>
>  in lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
>
>  in System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
>
>  in lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
>
>  in System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
>
>  in System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>
>  in System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
>  in System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

There weren't any modification in code on in database structure. Exception is thrown in a few places. Other applications (not windows services) runs properly with the same database. As I can check some queries runs ok, only a few of them throws this exception. Type are various. Sometimes it can't convert from string to int32 and sometimes (in other query) it can't convert from int32 to string.

To fix the problem we have to restart Windows service.

I don't have any problem with memory (my first suspect). Service use about 100-150MB of ram.

Environment: Framework 4.0, EF 6.1.3, 64bit, SQL Server 2012 Express.

Comment: Stable code does not just break over time or after running too long. Its a bug in your code. Somewhere there is variable or stored value that has an unexpected value. Perhaps you forgot to sanatize an input or maybe there is a persisted value that is encountered infrequently. As it is no one here could say why/where, not with the limited information given. Your best bet is to add logging to the method(s) affected and output the exact query that is being executed with parameters, then use that to figure out what is actually causing the problem.

Comment: It's in various places. I have full log. It works many days and suddenly it start crashing. It throws errors in the same places (it's not one query but 2-3 queries) that works before. Service do similiar work all the time and from the moment when it occurs service is not usable until someone will restart service. It looks like there is a problem with database connection but it crashes even if I have new database connection in method. I'm sure it's not a problem with one query. I have database first model so it has proper properties.

Comment: The only think I suspect is that I have one static db context. It should work like some kind of cache, but I change some queries to use new db context so it's rarely used. But in some places there are some simple quieries with use of this context. So maybe there is situation that two threads use the same context and it breaks. But quieries that throws exceptions use new db context. I don't know if static context could breake all other context.

Comment: Can't be answered without seeing code. A bounty is not gonna fix that.

Comment: @GrzegorzSawicki Did you manage to find a fix for your problem? I am experience the same thing as you described in your post (but using EF 6.4, ASP.NET Core, Linux, Azure SQL)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like to need to do alot of logging job here. What I recommend, is that first of all, debug the cases and write logs in each place your code throws exceptions.

As a matter of precaution, do try to check as best as possible if your properties in your object are convertible - using [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8):

```
if(int.TryParse(X, out intVar) 
{
}
else
{
   //failed to convert  
}
```

Use also try catch and issue a log error with the exact stack trace, this is preferable for string exceptions as you cannot do try parse on a string property.

There is no easy way here, you will have to dig this through piece by piece.